# Is (log-)standard deviation learned in TRPO and PPO or fixed instead?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, proximal-policy-optimization, trust-region-policy-optimization

After having read [Williams (1992)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00992696.pdf), where it was suggested that actually both the mean and standard deviation can be learned while training a REINFORCE algorithm on generating *continuous* output values, I assumed that this would be common practice nowadays in the domain of Deep Reinforcement Learning (DRL).
In the [supplementary material](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/schulman15.pdf) associated with the paper introducing [Trust Region Policy Optimization](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/schulman15.pdf) (TRPO), however, it is stated that:

> A neural network with several fully-connected
> (dense) layers maps from the input features to the mean of a Gaussian distribution. A separate set of parameters specifies the log standard deviation of each element. More concretely, the parameters include a set of weights and biases for the neural network computing the mean, $\{W_i , b_i\}_{i=1}^L$ , and a vector $r$ (log standard deviation) with the same dimension as $a$. Then, the policy is defined by the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\text{mean}=\text{NeuralNet}(s; \{W_i , b_i\}_{i=1}^L), \text{stdev}=\text{exp}(r))$.

where $s$ refers to a state and $a$ to a predicted action (respectively a vector of actions if multiple outputs are generated concurrently).

To me this suggests that the standard deviation stdev (being a function of $r$) is actually not learned when training a TRPO agent, but that it is solely determined by some possibly constant vector $r$.

Since I found the idea of adjusting both the mean and standard deviation together when training a REINFORCE agent quite reasonable, I got wondering whether it is actually true that TRPO agents do not treat the standard deviation for sampling output values as a trainable parameter, but just as a function of the state-independent vector $r$.
(Pretty much the same shall then apply to [Proximal Policy Optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) (PPO) agents as well, since they are reported to follow TRPO's model architecture in the continuous output case.)

In search for an answer, I browsed OpenAI's baselines repository containing reference implementations of both TRPO and PPO.
In my understanding of their [code](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/ea25b9e8b234e6ee1bca43083f8f3cf974143998/baselines/common/distributions.py#L104), the code seems to confirm my assumption that standard deviation is a non-trainable parameter and that it is, instead of being trainable, taken to be a constant.

Now, I was wondering whether my understanding of the procedure how TRPO (and PPO) computes standard deviation(s) is correct or whether I misunderstood or overlooked something important here.

Comment: Hi, have found a confirmation? I have the same question as yours.

Comment: It’s a modelling choice. You can learn it, or fix it to a value of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Using PPO from stable baselines 3, I see clearly that the variance of the actions are reducing in the environment I am using, where the optimal actions are static and not dependent on the state. This seems to suggest that the log_std parameter is being learned for the SBL3 implementation.

In the docs for the SBL3-PPO, the description says log_std_init is the initial value which also suggests it is a learned parameter.

log_std_init (float) – Initial value for the log standard deviation

Of course, it is ultimately a design choice whether you want to make this parameter learnable.

Update: Upon inspecting the PPO paper again, it is stated that they using linear annealing of the log_std parameter. However, when I inspect the log_std parameter in my experiments which start at 0 and has 3 dimensions, the values are not the same. This leads me to think there is both annealing and learning at the same time.